# BroadcastReceiver doesn't show SMS not Send or Not delivered

Tags: android, sms

While using broadcastreceiver for checking sms status, it shows the toast when sms is sent but shows nothing when sms is not sent or delivered (im testing it by putting an abrupt number). 
the code I'm using is the one I've seen the most on every site of checking sms delivery status. But my code is only showing the status when sms is sent successfully.
Can any one get a hint of what am I doing wrong?
I hav this method in doInBackground() and so obviously im using AsyncTask.

```
public void send_SMS(String list, String msg, AtaskClass task)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

              switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(list,",");    
        int count= st.countTokens();
        int i =1;
        count = 1;

            while(st.hasMoreElements())

            {

                //  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, SMS.class),0);

                    String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();

                    //SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    sms.sendTextMessage(tempMobileNumber, null, msg , sentPI, deliveredPI); 

                      Double cCom = ((double)i/count) * 100; 


                    int j = cCom.intValue();

              task.doProgress(j);
              i++;
              count ++;
               }

     // class ends
    }
```

Comment: So it doesn't show the Toast- does onReceive fire? If you do a Log.d in there, is it logged?

Comment: Im sure onRecive fires since i always get a "sms sent" and "sms delivered" toast when i give it a correct number. Also i tried to chk it with Log.d ... but Log.d only shows for "RESULT_OK", means when sms is sent, but for all other errors, it is not logged.

Can it be that when sms is delivered it gets the results immediately and shows sms is sent, but when its not yet delivered it needs time to figure it out ??? if so how am i able to test it :(